# Xcode: building two apps on one same server simultaneously

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, devops

I'm new to Xcode and any apple-related stuff, so my question may sound dumb (soory guys, newbies problem!) but is it possible to run two build jobs on the same mac in the same time? Like first CI jobs starts building an app and second starts a  few moments later , so they are effectively simultaniously.

Comment: Assuming the code bases are in different folders, why not? (Though you'll need a powerful machine to run XCode compilation twice, at any useful speed.)

Comment: Hmm, looks like a solution. I'll test it out, thank you.)